# How can I find out which styles in my css are not being applied in ie8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, compatibility

My client uses ie8 and the site I made for them works fine in all other browsers EXCEPT ie8. Most things are out of place and I can't figure out what styles are causing this to happen. I am now using ie conditional styling, but I don't know what to put in my stylesheet since I am not sure what attributes are not showing up.

Anyone know a software that compared your style css to what styles are actually being used?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're running the latest IE, run the developer tools (press F12 while viewing your webpage, or go to IE's Tools -> F12 Developer Tools menu), and select the Emulation tab, then change the document mode to IE8. You can then inspect the element that's causing the issue. Unfortunately you'll have to do trial by elimination in order to find out what styles are or aren't being used.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no software that will automate this for you, but you can check for this yourself at ['http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS'](http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS)

This keeps very up-to-date data on browsers and their feature compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing F12 to access developer tools?  If you click on the DOM explorer tab, you can browse through the code.

Once you find the part of the code you are interested in, you can click on it and see the relevant css in the panel on the right.

I've posted a photo here: http://epic-xp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/test.png